# What is 'Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql

Thanks for the help...

I have the following:

```
INSERT INTO Products (A,B,C) VALUES (1, 2, 3)
```

I get the error 'Subquery returns more than 1 row'

I have used this query over and over in my structure, but it fails on this one particular set of values. It is pretty straight forward.

What am I looking for?

Comment: `INSERT INTO Products (A,B,C) VALUES ('1', '2', '3');`

Comment: Maybe there is a trigger on this table that causes this error?

Comment: Is this really the query that's giving you error? if yes What are the type of field A, B, C?

Comment: The error can not come from this part of your SQL. It must be from a subquery.

Comment: This is the query that throws the error...I just received it on an UPDATE Products set Toggle=1 where id=1256

Comment: field types are A=int(11), B=float(5,2), C=int(11)

Comment: have you used any SELECT query instead of value 1256 in the UPDATE query.

Comment: You received it on an update? What does that mean? Clearly, this is not an update. As others have suggested, perhaps you have a trigger

Comment: Yes, it's probably a trigger. I'm looking through them...I just don't see it yet...thanks for the help.